# WordPress Visit Site is pointing to another URL

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to repair a WordPress installation. I almost have it running now, but there is a strange issue.

In the admin dashboard there is an option in the upper menu to open the site, Visit Site.
When clicking this menu option, the browser opens another folder from the server, not the folder where WordPress is installed.
I have tried several options to solve the issue:

1. Adding

   define('WP_HOME','https://yourdomain.com');
   define('WP_SITEURL','https://yourdomain.com'); 
   at the end of wp-config.php file. Of course changin yourdomain.com for the current domain.
2. Checking the database entries for siteurl and home in options table.
3. Checking inside Settings->General settings for WordPress Address and Site Address

Is there another way to get the reason for the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a few other factors you are missing to mention in your question. I would add checking the server setup for that domain.  Is it cPanel or Plesk?  Take a look at what the domain is supposed to be vs what path is WP installed.

Other possibilities might be:

1. Server's cache
2. Your .htaccess file
3. Permalinks (disable and enable)

Comment: I am using cPanel

Comment: The I would go to domains area and make sure that the Wordpress installation is where it is supposed to be.  Maybe it is installed on a subfolder of that domain or maybe there are conflicts with subdomains already installed on that folder.